# Why does self.tablview.rowHeight not return height from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I need to set the height for just one row programmatically, all the other rows are static cells created in the Storyboard with different heights.

In my code the 5th cell should be "hidden" as default, therefore I want to set the height of this row to 0.0. All the other cells should use their height from the Storyboard, I'm using the method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` to set the height of the cells.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat height = self.tableView.rowHeight;

    if (indexPath.row == 4)
    {
        height = 0.0f;
    }

    return height;
}
```

The problem is that `self.tableView.rowHeight` always returns `658` as height, which is a totally wrong value.

Comment: 4th Cell? Then the row should be equated with 3 I think! if (indexPath.row == 3)

Comment: sry that was my fault, I ment the 5th cell. But this is not the problem unfortunately.

Comment: what is self.tableView ? is it binded ? I believe you don't need the "self." in the first line.

Comment: I tried just tableView.rowHeight as well, but this makes no difference.

Comment: 658 is like really weird, are you sure you haven't mix up tableview height and tableviewcell height in your storyboard. (and 658 and 568 btw)

Comment: Actually @Justafinger has a valid point, can you check, that the rowHeight is not set to 658 => http://i.stack.imgur.com/plqmh.png

Comment: OMG...you are right, rowHeight was set to 658. But now I'm facing another problem I can't set this value, because I have so many different row heights.

Comment: If you have a finite number of cell, you should probably do it all in heightForRowAtIndexPath with a switch on indexPath.row

Answer (score 0):

If you implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you need to set a value for all cells or you will run into stuff like this. What you can do is the following:

```
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     switch (indexPath.row){
           case 4:
                return 0;

           default:

               static NSNumber *height;
               UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];
               height = @(cell.bounds.size.height);
               return [height floatValue];
      }
 }
```

Comment: Yes, I have set that.

Comment: And you are using that identifier in `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"]`

Comment: Yes, I used exactly the identifier from the storyboard.